# Deploy procedure for new dags

Tags: airflow

I need some advice on how to restart all airflow services on deploy without killing the workers in the middle of a task.

I've written a deployment procedure for my DAGs which installs airflow and any other pip dependencies in a virtualenv.  Once my release directory is ready, I:

1. stop airflow-flower, airflow-worker, airflow-scheduler, and airflow-webserver
2. Update the "current" simlink to point to my new release
3. Start airflow-flower, airflow-worker, airflow-scheduler, and airflow-webserver

The problem with this deploy procedure is that the workers get killed immediately. I'd like to add some sort of monitoring to the script to pause all DAGs, wait for the workers to idle, then restart the services, but the airflow CLI has no way to learn which dags are enabled nor whether the workers are idle.

I understand that many of the airflow services can auto-detect changes in the dags folder, but I want each deployment to have its own virtualenv. If I don't restart all services then a new deployment won't pick up a new line in my requirements.txt file.

Comment: I'm straggling with same problem, did you find a way or you had to implement everything mentioned in accepted answer?

Comment: I actually noticed that workers will gracefully quit from a SIGINT.  I updated my systemctl script accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow workers gracefully quit from a SIGINT.  Update your process monitor to quit with SIGINT instead of the default. If you're using systemctl, then it will look something like this:

```
...
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=...
KillSignal=SIGINT
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

...
```

Comment: This isn't really the answer for the original question. It is a wonderful answer for gracefully shutting down an Airflow worker with a Systemd unit file.

Answer (score 5):

You have access to the Airflow DB so consider developing a deployment script that does this process for you.

- Update the DAG table to pause all DAGs
- Read the TASK_INSTANCE table to wait until all RUNNING state tasks complete
- Restart Airflow services.
- Update the DAG table to unpause DAGs.

Comment: A bit roundabout, but clever. Would be nice if this functionality were baked into airflow. (Say a global pause/unpause from CLI + wait_for workers to idle)

Comment: consider raising a feature request - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel

Comment: Will do.  Also, this answer got me 90% of the way there, but I encountered issues along the way.  Airflow-scheduler needs to be stopped otherwise the workers keep running tasks that already succeeded. I also had to use the celery API to query the workers rather than trust the data in the task_instance table.

Comment: In the "Restart Airflow services." I should have been more explicit. I meant restart the master scheduler and the workers. On querying celery, my understandinghmmm is celery comment. Celery just holds the backlog

Comment: In the "Restart Airflow services." I should have been more explicit. I meant restart the master scheduler and the workers. On querying celery, my understanding is celery just holds the backlog that is yet to be run. So in order to restart running tasks you still have to go against the db.